# Alternative to file gets content and curl to get html code from a page

Tags: php, curl, get

I am using the following code to get the html code of a page and extract the price later on for a price comparator :

```
<?php
function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (function_exists('curl_exec')){ 
        $conn = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,  true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $url_get_contents_data = (curl_exec($conn));
        curl_close($conn);
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        $url_get_contents_data = file_get_contents($url);
    }elseif(function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('stream_get_contents')){
        $handle = fopen ($url, "r");
        $url_get_contents_data = stream_get_contents($handle);
    }else{
        $url_get_contents_data = false;
    }
    return $url_get_contents_data;
} 

$html = url_get_contents("http://linktopage.com");
echo $html;
?>
```

However one of the website i want to get the price of an item from blocks this method and shows me 'your ip has been banned'.
Is there an other way than file_gets_content (same result) and curl (code above) to get a html code from a page ?

If there is a better method to my problem that would be great too.
Regards.

Comment: If your IP has been flagged by one of the servers you're trying to scrape, you're out of luck regardless of which method you choose to use to contact that server.  You'll need to get a new IP address, or execute your code on another machine that hasn't been blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nate! That's right, mmh.

Comment: Curl allows you to send any information to the server you want. If you are able to copy the headers that your browser sends then the server has no way to distinguish you from a normal user. user-agent header and use of cookies are especially important. For example: user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36

Comment: Also, generally speaking: to reduce the chance of being blacklisted while scraping an external server, you should probably throttle the number of requests you send per minute.

Answer (score 1):

If your IP banned, you should use proxy servers. "cURL" library can work with proxy, set CURLOPT_PROXY and other proxy-options in "curl_setopt" function.

Comment: Thank you, i will look into that.